# jQuery Expanding Navigation with Body classes

Tags: jquery, css

Every page on my site has multiple body classes that I use CSS selectors with, like so: <body class="category subcategory page">

I would like to be able to automatically add the class 'expanded' to the menu item in the left nav if it matches the final class in that declaration.

So far, my understanding of it is that I can set a variable to the body's last class name using className().last(); and then just write and if statement to determine if the menu item (an unordered list item) matches it and addClass('expanded');

But it's not working. Would someone be kind enough to help me with the syntax? I'm still a bit new to JavaScript.

```
$(document).ready(function  () {
    var pageclass=('body').className().last();
    if ($('div.nav-menu li').hasClass(pageclass)){
        $(this).addClass('current');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if `className()` is a real method.. Try this:

```
var last_class = $('body').attr('class').split(' ').slice(-1);
if ($('div.nav-menu li.arrowed').hasClass(last_class)){
    ..
}
```

Comment: Tried it and the variable comes up as undefined in firebug. This is my syntax:

    $(document).ready(function () {
     var last_class = $('body').attr('class').split(' ').slice(-1);
     if ($('div.nav-menu li').hasClass(last_class)){
      $(this).addClass('current');
     }
    });

Comment: Thanks for checking this for me. Is there anything I should check for that might screw up var definitions on my site?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: OK, so I found that the var is working ok now. I guess there's something wrong with my if statement.